# is SimpleStringSchema from the two path in jar the same?

Tags: apache-flink

In intellij,`SimpleStringSchema` can be imported from two places.

`import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;`

`import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;`

are they always the same for our project?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Their behavior should be the same because the one in `org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization` extends the one in `org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization`. I am not exactly sure why there were two classes created though.

It's worth mentioning that You should use only `org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema` as the other one has been deprecated.